# What is the number of Sylow 2-subgroups of the symmetric group $S_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to find the number of Sylow 2-sbgroups of the symmetric group S5. As  $ \lvert S_5 \rvert =120=2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$. It has 2-SSG, 3-SSG, 5-SSG. But how to calculate there numbers? What is the general formula to calculate it.

Comment: Since a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_5$ fixes a unique point, it might help to observe that the total number is equal to five times the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_4$.

Answer (score 2):

There are $15$ Sylow-$2$-subgroups of $S_5$. For a proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376586/on-the-number-of-sylow-subgroups-in-symmetric-group?rq=1). It equals
$\frac{|S_5|}{|P|}=\frac{120}{8}=15$. By Sylow's theorem we have $n_2(S_5)\in \{ 1,3,5,15\}$, and it is easy to show that $n_2(S_5)\ge 6$, so the result follows.