# How many sylow 5 subgroups in S7?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Number of sylow 5 subgroups in $S_{7}$ is?
$|S_{7}|  =5040= 2^4 \times 3^2 \times 5\times 7$. number of sylow 5 subgroups is by sylow 3rd theorem n5=1+5k=possibilities are$\left\{1,6,16,21,36,56,126,336,1008\right\}$.we know that sylow subgroup exist of order 5 is cyclic . O(Sylow 5 subgroup)=5.Suppose  we have 6 sylow subgroup then each sylow subgroup order 5 elements is 4 totally we have 24 elements of order 5 is it possible?

Comment: This has been answered on many forums, e.g., [here](https://www.numerade.com/ask/question/points-recall-that-the-symmetric-group-sv-has-7-elements-show-that-each-sylow-5-subgroup-of-sz-is-cyclic-how-many-sylow-5-subgroups-does-sz-have-justify-your-answer-without-appealing-to-sylo-26063/). Every such Sylow subgroup is cyclic, so it suffices to count the elements of order $5$.

Comment: In a p group number of p order elements is (p-1). So number of 5 order elements in cyclic group of order 5 is 4.

Comment: Yes, but your list of possibilities is not correct, because $s_5\mid 2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 7=1008$, so $s_5$ can be bigger than $56$. How many Sylow subgroups can you form from the $504$ elements of order $5$?

Comment: 1008 =3(mod 5) but we need 1(mod 5) so 1008 not in the list.1+5k does not divide 1008

Comment: I didn't say $s_5=1008$. It is only a *divisor*. Your list ends with $56$. *Why?*

Comment: Yes  336 also in the list. Thanks

Comment: Thanks i need one clarification. But sylow 2 subgroups exist of order 16 . but 16 order group need not be cyclic. Then what technique need to count number of sylow 2subgroup inS7

Comment: One step after the other. You still forgot some numbers in your list. For Sylow-$2$ subgroups, have a look at the methods, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664104/what-is-the-number-of-sylow-2-subgroups-of-the-symmetric-group-s-5).

Comment: So number of sylow 5 subgroups in S7=126 is it correct?